# How do i use VideoView on SplashScreen API android?

Tags: android, firebase

I have a VideoView in SplashScreenActivity on the present application. I could see google recommends SplashScreen API for the devices running on android 12 and higher. Could someone help me out with this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you simply can't, new splash screen API is intended to consolidate and unify start of all apps, you can't freely modify its GUI